# Ошибка Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"

Tags: node.js, npm, babel

Пытаюсь запустить дев сервер командой `npm run start:dev`. Выдает ошибку, что в заголовке. Код всех файлов привожу.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "15.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "clean": "rimraf build && mkdirp build",
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./src -s --copy-files",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://git@gitlab.com:mh_koval/nodejs.git"
  },
  "author": "Mykhayl Koval <mykhaylkoval@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://git@gitlab.com:mh_koval/nodejs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://git@gitlab.com:mh_koval/nodejs#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

nodemon.json

```
{
  "watch": [
    "src",
    ".env"
  ],
  "ext": "js, json",
  "ignore": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "exec": "babel-node ./src/index.js"
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ],
  "ignore": []
}
```

Структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы поменяли только package.json версию babel?

Comment: Сначала написал код во всех файлах, а потом `npm install`.

Comment: Думаю вам нужно удалить package-lock.gson и node_modules. И установить заново пакеты

Comment: Просто бывает и старые тоже лежать там.

Comment: и приходится переустанавливать из-за lock

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866494/how-do-you-reinstall-an-apps-dependencies-using-npm) при проблемах с версиями это переустановка модулей. Удаление package-lock.json и node_modules и новая установка пакетов.
попробуйте удалить глобально `babel-core`

> I used the following to check global dependencies.
>
> npm list -g --depth 0
>
> Found a bable package and I removed it globally.
>
> npm uninstall -g babel-core
>
> Deleted my package-lock.json
>
> Then reinstalled it locally
>
> npm i --save-dev @babel/core

Comment: Не сработало так

Comment: :(( идет поиск решения

Comment: может тут оно https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8482

Comment: Может так поможет?

Comment: Даже когда я после удаления node_modues и package-lock.json запускаю команду `babel --version`,  то выдает 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3). Команда `npm list -g --depth 0` выдает └── (empty)

Comment: npm uninstall -g babel-core

Comment: потом npm install

Comment: У вас он глобально установлен

Comment: Не работает, ладно, тут не найти на данный момент решения.

Comment: Найдите на компьютере ваш старый бабель и удалите

Comment: Windows 7, 8 and 10 - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

Comment: Короче, сработало только с yarn.

Comment: Ну хорошо хоть так